# Select2 multiselect not working in dynamic table form mvc 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a form where we need to develop dynamic table form. We have used select2 plugin to multi select the dropdown. But when we add new row select2 gets disabled and when we reinitialize the following problem occurred. So please suggest how to resolve this issue.

function addTableRow(table) {

```
        var $ttc = $(table).find("tbody tr:last");
        var $tr = $ttc.clone();


        $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", function () { // find name in the cloned row
            var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)_(\d+)__(\D+)$/); // extract parts from id, including index
            if (parts) {

                return parts[1] + "[" + ++parts[2] + "]." + parts[3]; // build new name
            }
        }).attr("id", function () { // change id also
            var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)_(\d+)__(\D+)$/); // extract parts
            if (parts) {
                return parts[1] + "_" + ++parts[2] + "__" + parts[3]; // build new id
            }
        });
        $tr.find("span[data-valmsg-for]").attr("data-valmsg-for", function () { // find validation message

            var parts = $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for").match(/(\D+)\[(\d+)]\.(\D+)$/); // extract parts from the referring attribute
            if (parts) {
                return parts[1] + "[" + ++parts[2] + "]." + parts[3]; // build new value
            }
        });


        //$ttc.find(".new-row").attr("class", "btn btn-danger remove-row").attr("title", "Delete row").unbind("click").click(deleteRow).empty().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'> </i>"); // change buttin function

        if (table == "#skills-table") {
            $tr.find(".new-row").click(addRow); // add function to the cloned button
        }
        if (table == "#uniqueIdenifier-table") {
            $tr.find(".new-row").click(addUniqueRow); // add function to the cloned button
        }
        if (table == "#OtherBankList-table") {
            $tr.find(".new-row").click(addOtherBankListRow); // add function to the cloned button
        }
        if (table == "#childorganisation-table") {
            $tr.find(".new-row").click(addOtherChildListRow); // add function to the cloned button
        }

        // reset fields in the new row
        $tr.find("select").val("");
        $tr.find("input[type=text]").val("");
        $tr.find("input[type=hidden]").val("");
        // add cloned row as last row
        $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);

        // Find the affected form
        var $form = $tr.closest("FORM");

        // Unbind existing validation
        $form.unbind();
        $form.data("validator", null);

        // Check document for changes
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

        var _select = $tr.find('.select2');
        if (_select) {
            //console.log(_select);
            initializeSelect2(_select);
        }



        // We could re-validate with changes
        // $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
    };

    function initializeSelect2(selectElementObj) {
        //selectElementObj.select2("destroy");            
        selectElementObj.select2();

    }
```

Comment: Show some code, if not one one can help you solving the issue

Comment: I have attached the code in above question. can u please suggest what to do to make it work